# React onClick event firing for child element

Tags: reactjs, events, event-bubbling

Click Handler.

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
  }
```

Return.

```
{ menu.map((menuItem, index) => (
      <div onClick={handleClick}>
          <div>{menuItem.text}</div>
          <img src={menuItem.image} /></div>
          ))
        }
```

My console tells me that the event.target is the IMG element instead of the DIV. Why is this happening and how can I lock the event to the parent DIV? Do I just have to write logic to look at the IMG parent element?

Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because [Bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). `event.target` is the “target” element that initiated the event. it's the event that you clicked on it and in this case, it was an image. I think you can get div by `event.currentTarget` because the handler runs on it.

Comment: Well would you look at that! I was unaware of currentTarget. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your code, but forcing the scope to the one of the div should work as well:

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
  }

{
   menu.map((menuItem, index) => (
      <div onClick={evt => handleClick(evt)}>
          <div>{menuItem.text}</div>
          <img src={menuItem.image} /></div>
          ))
        }
```

Which is basically what you had, but I edited `<div onClick={evt => handleClick(evt)}>`.